# Bootstrap Jumbotron stretching

Tags: html

I have a bootstrap header on this site that you can see here: http://www.healthunit.org/checkeredflags/index.html

I am wondering if there is a way for me to have the image stop expanding after, say x pixels and have it static, with black bars on each side. That is, the image would stay the same size but as the screen got stretched, a black background would show behind the image as needed. Here is the jumbotron:

```
<header>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <img class="img-responsive image" src="Images/CheckFlag.png" alt="Checkered Flags Banner">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `max-width` css property.

```
 <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color: black;">
   <img class="center-block image img-responsive" src="Images/CheckFlag.png" alt="" style="max-width: 400px;">
</div>
```